# In practice, does the order of a series RLC-shunt circuit matter?

Tags: rf, filter, impedance, series, impedance-matching

In simulation I'm finding that the image pictured below works well to optimize a complex impedance match.  I know that Z = ZL + ZC + R, so in theory the order shouldn't matter---but in practice, with physical components, does the order of the series RLC components work "better" in some situations?

- For example: should DC components be nearer to the RF line, or vice-versa?
- Other considerations?

(In this case the shunt side is a FET drain bias, so the capacitor must be there somewhere to prevent a DC short.)

[image: Series RLC Shunt Circuit]

Comment: Parasitic components, stray inductance and capacitance, will affect the circuit in different ways according to the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulation is correct: the order doesn't matter.  The thing that will matter is the proximity of the components to other components, and as @Brian Drummond said, parasitic components, stray inductance and capacitance.  There is no generic rule about putting the ground tied components before or after the inline components.